# cpp multiple inheritance unexpected ctor called

Tags: c++, constructor, multiple-inheritance

Why does `Down`not invoke the `Base` ctor  through `Left` & `Right` twice?

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() { cout << "base-ctor" << endl; }
    Base(string a) { cout << a << endl; }
};

class Left : virtual public Base {
public:
    Left(string a) : Base(a) {}
};

class Right : virtual public Base {
public:
    Right(string a) : Base(a) {}
};

class Down : public Left, public Right {
public:
    Down(string a) : Left(a), Right(a) {}
};

int main() {
    Down x("down");
    // -> base-ctor
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using virtual inheritance from base class:

```
class Left : virtual public Base {
class Right : virtual public Base {
```

if you want to have it invoced twice, remove the **virtual** keyword:

```
class Left : public Base {
class Right : public Base {
```

This article might be useful for you, if you want to avoid a 'diamond problem':
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem

Answer (score 0):

Why should it? That it does not is literally *the whole point* of virtual inheritance, which you've opted to use in your code sample. I guess you decided to use it without researching what it does.

As for this behaviour being "incorrect", well, by definition it is your expectation that is incorrect.